# como ejecutar una function que se aplique en un componente hermano?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, callback

Buen dia,
este es un caso de uso de eventos, usando Mobx

tengo dos componentes hermanos, uno App y otro win, win es un popout que se ejecuta de forma normal y solo muestra datos que se almacenan en un store gestionado con mobx

estoy usando:  makeObservable, action, observable como se ve a continuacion.

```
import { makeObservable, action, observable }   from 'mobx'
```

en win hay una secuencia como esta,

```
return (
        RapidStore.targetas.map(card =>(
            card.visible > 0 ?
                <div 
                    key={card.id}
                    className={'rapid-elementowin ' + card.color }
                >   
                    <div className="rapid-elemento-espaciowin"> 
                        <h1 className="rapid-elento-textwin">{ card.titulo }</h1>
                        <ul>{
                            RapidStore.citas.map(user =>(
                                user.id_consulta === card.id ?
                                    <li
                                        key={ user.id_cita }
                                    > {  user.nombre + " " + user.apellp }
                                    </li>
                                :""
                            ))
                        }</ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            :"" 
        ))
    )
```

El objetivo es actulizar el render cuando el array citas cambie usando algun evento desde App, en mi caso sucede cuando ejecute

```
RapidStore.agregar_citas({
                        id_cita:            estado[0].id_cola
                    })
```

Esto pasa por **makeObservable** que esta atento y sabe que realizara una **action** con esa funcion.

```
constructor () {
            makeObservable(this, {
            ...
                citas: observable,
                agregar_citas: action,
           .....
            })
        }
```

y bueno, lo que sigue es que se ejecuta la funcion.

```
agregar_citas = (cita) => {
        this.citas.push(cita)

    }
```

que asu ves agrega mas datos a mi array **citas** que por cierto esta con la decoracion **observable**,

cuando sucede todo esto, en win el render vuelve ejecutarse mostando los datos cambiados. no olvidar que **observer** debe estar ejecutandose para realizar dichos cambios.

```
export default observer(Win);
```

**mi error fue que olvide hacer observable mi array citas y por eso no se refrescaban los cambios realizados en win.**

espero ayudar en algo, a alguien que lo nececite y usa mobx.

saludos.

Comment: Por qué hiciste un hermano de App? Técnicamente es el componente de más jerarquía. En tal caso que quieras dejarlo así no es posible pasar datos de un componente hermano a otro. El pasaje de datos es padre-hijo.

Comment: lo solucione, omiti la propiedad obserbable de mobx

Comment: seria exelenete que movieras tu comentario a respuesta para aceptarla y cerrar este tema gracias.

Comment: Pero tu lo resolviste amigo. O le qué te comenté te fue de ayuda?

Comment: Asi es amigo, tu conmentario me hiso desperatar y revisar el codigo denuevo tu lo lograste.

Comment: Bueno, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En React la información viaja en componente a componente en relación padre-hijo, y no es posible compartir datos entre hermanos. En tal caso qué se requiera qué cierta porción de o todo el código tenga acceso a información centralizada, se pueden utilizar Contexts, véase aquí: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html.

Comment: Excelente, ayuda saludos.